# php filter_var fails with zero on FILTER_VALIDATE_INT

Tags: php

I'm confused the following throws an exception:

```
if (!filter_var(0, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
    throw new Exception("Non numeric field passed " . $field . " when expecting a number: " . $variable . " passed instead");
```

anything positive works fine? I've tried intval(0) and still nothing. is zero not an integer?

Answer (score 16):

People should test **false** instead:

```
if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
    // $value is not an integer
}
```

Comment: But what if the input can range between 0 - 100000?

Comment: Another reason why the lack of type safety is literally trouble in this language.

Answer (score 9):

**[filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)**  Returns the **filtered data**, or FALSE if the filter fails.

`filter_var(0, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` returns `int(0)`, and is a falsy value, `!filter_var(0, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` will be true.

Comment: But what if the input can range between 0 - 100000?

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 because of rand of Integer is -2^31 => 2^31, 0 - 100000 is a child of the aggregate